# Getting strtotime('last monday') relative to some other date

Tags: php, date

What I'm trying to do is calculate the timestamp of last monday, but relative to some other date.
Say I give the date 16-11-2011, I want to get the date 14-11-2011 back.

Is there a way to do this without hardcoding it?

Comment: `echo date("y m d", strtotime('last monday', strtotime($old_date)));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the 2nd parameter of [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to set the "now" time, which is used when calculating relative dates:

```
strtotime('last monday', strtotime($old_date));
```

Comment: Or "-1 week" or "-7 days", etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could set now. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.